# Chamada de função JS em método Html.EditorFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou criando um CRUD para Endereços a serem gravados no banco de dados e, para preenchimento automático do mesmo, estou utilizando o [ViaCEP](https://viacep.com.br/). Quando fiz o formulário utilizando elementos HTML deu tudo certo porém quando utilizo o método Html.EditorFor não consigo fazer a chamada da função JS `pesquisacep();` no momento em que o campo sai de foco (`onblur=""`).

É possível fazer a chamada da função JS no Html.EditorFor() ou preciso realizar a chamada em outro método?

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Endereco</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cep, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } });
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cep, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Já tentei adicionar a chamada como atributo do Html.EditorFor porém sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifiquei que, para adicionar elementos no Html.EditorFor() é necessária a anotação `@` antes da chamada. foi adicionado então o `@onblur="pesquisacep(this.value)"` e o problema foi corrigido.

Código final:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
<h4>Endereco</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cep, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onblur="pesquisacep(this.value)" } });
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cep, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```